# In user_db design which design would be more manageable?

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

I am trying to design the user database that has an administrator, manager, user. I thought of two ways.

The first one is the user has a `role` column and will make relation between user-manager with an `user_manager` table like this. The user can be an administrator, manager or an user by role number (ex: role 0 is admin, role 1 is manager, role 2 is user).

[image]

The second way is making administrator, manager, user tables separately and creating a relationship between manager and user like this:

[image]

Which method would be more manageable and productive?

Could you give me some opinions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Answer (score 1):

I'll create a user table for the common information among the roles, a role table and then a mapping table to link both, you can use userID and rolesID from the first two tables as foreign keys on the third one.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with your first approach. I wouldn't want to end up in a scenario where I'm trying to hunt down a user that could be in 1 of 3 different tables.

In addition, you could define a user's role in a separate user_role table in case down the road you would want an account with multiple permissions. However, if you don't think that would be applicable in your case then don't bother!